# Internalization, workflow between translator and developer

Tags: json, reactjs, translation

Sorry for my bad english

On our project, we are going to implement internalization, in this case I'm using i18, specifically 'react-i18next'. The translations are based on the locales folder within the public folder.

My question is, how should the **workflow** look like between **developer** and the **translator**. Usually does the translator directly change the json (***making them learn how to read json)*** or do they just translate the text of the website on a paper and it's up to the developer who understands the structure of json to manually add/change the translated texts.

This is an example of the structure of the locales folder, there are two folders of language, one being "en" and the other "zh", both containing json files with same names but different translations.

[Locales folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6zOO.png)
[The json files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoxKh.png)

This is an example of the implementation on a button
[Locales implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxzFz.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [i18nexus.com](https://i18nexus.com). It's a platform built to work specifically with react-i18next. Just import your translation files, and connect i18next directly to i18nexus. You can then invite translators to edit and confirm translations there. It is really easy to set up.

Here's a 5 minute React tutorial: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-localization-the-winner-is-i18next-i18nexus-b7cd9f14094e

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you should use a translation platform for that purpose:

- you upload files to the translation platform,
- translators translate in UI tailored for them,
- you receive translated files back.

There are a lot of platforms to choose from:

- [Lokalise](https://lokalise.com/) (commercial) -- disclaimer: I'm working here
- [Mojito](https://www.mojito.global/) (open-source)
- [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) (commercial)
- [LingoHub](https://lingohub.com/) (commercial)
- [Locize](https://locize.com/?lng=en) (commercial)
- [Phrase](https://phrase.com/) (commercial)
- [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) (commercial)
- [Weblate](https://weblate.org/en-gb/) (open-source)
- [Zanata](http://zanata.org/) (open-source)

Answer (score 0):

Many translators are familiar with many file formats and have the required tools to process them directly. Others are less technologically savvy and rely on the client (who usually has the requisite scripting know-how) or an intermediary to bring the strings into a more manageable format like Excel or CSV.

So it's up to you and your translators (or your linguistic service provider if you use one to manage all languages in one place) to negotiate a workflow that makes good use of your respective talents to get good results with a reasonable amount of effort and cost.

The most important thing you will want to worry about (and something that no tool will relieve you of) is providing context for translators. If they don't know where exactly the string they are translating is used, you'll get poor results.